# ApplicationContext.MainForm not responsive to Process.CloseMainWindow()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

I have a custom `ApplicationContext`:

```
static void Main()
{
    /// ...
    MyApplicationContext applicationContext = new MyApplicationContext();
    Application.Run(applicationContext);
}
```

And in the constructor for `MyApplicationContext` the main form is set:

```
private AppForm appForm = null;

public MyApplicationContext() : base()
{
    /// init...

    appForm = new AppForm();
    this.MainForm = appForm;

    /// more init...
}
```

In another application, I reference the above Process by process ID and send a `CloseMainWindow()` command.

```
using (Process parentProcess = Process.GetProcessById(processID))
{
    bool result = parentProcess.CloseMainWindow(); /// false
    ///...
}
```

However this method returns `False`.  [Microsoft says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the return value for `CloseMainWindow()` will be:

> **true** if the close message was successfully sent; **false** if the associated process does not have a main window or if the main window is disabled (for example if a modal dialog is being shown).

A call to `WaitForExit(int)` times out every time.  A call to `Kill()` does terminate the process.

There are definitely no dialog boxes showing.  What other reasons would cause the main form to be disabled?  How can I determine why this call is returning `False`?

Answer (score 0):

The form must be visible i.e. `Show()` must have been called for it to receive the `CloseMainWindow()` message.  If the form has been hidden with `form.Hide()` it will not receive the message.